# when are constructors called and how to not call them

Tags: c++, constructor

```
class A
{
    public:
    A(){std::cout << "hello\n";}
};

class B
{
    A object;
    public:
    B(A aObject){ object = aObject;}
};

int main() {

    A object;
    B bObject(object);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program it seems I construct class A twice because on my console "hello" is printed out twice. So my question is where exactly I'm calling my constructor for A and how I would make it stop so I only construct A once, while still passing an A object into B.

Comment: A substantially more inquisitive topic, "why you would NOT want to call them." Regardless, you're code constructs **three** `A` objects; one stand-alone, one by copy-construction (which you don't see evidence of because you don't log it), and a third as a member of the `B` object you likewise construct. If that isn't obvious, you should probably take @zaufi's advice and review the language basics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because your `B` class contains a member of type `A`.  As part of the construction of `B`, the `B::object` member is constructed, which requires a call to the `A` constructor.  So you actually have two `A` instances: `object` and `bObject.object`.

Because you did not put `object` in `B::B()`'s initializer list, `B::object` is default-constructed.  `object = aObject;` then *assigns to the existing `A` stored in `object`*.  So rather than copy-constructing `B::object`, you default-construct it (which is responsible for the second "hello" you see) and then you assign a new value to it.

The compiler will provide a copy-constructor `A(const A &)` for you, so you can copy-construct `B::object` from the parameter like so:

```
B(A aObject) : object(aObject) { }
```

This constructor does not call the default constructor, nor does it contain the code contained in the default constructor.  Therefore, calling this constructor does *not* cause output of "hello".

Note that you would still be constructing a new `A` (in fact you would be doing so twice, because `aObject` is passed by value) but since you did not define the copy-constructor yourself, it wouldn't contain your code that writes a string to `std::cout`.

The actual sequence of relevant events that happen here is:

1. `A object;` calls the `A::A()` constructor.  *(The first "hello" is printed from here.)*
2. `B bObject(object);` will call the `B::B(A)` constructor, but because the `A` argument is accepted by value, `object` is first copied into a new, temporary `A` using the compiler-generated `A::A(const A &)` copy constructor.
3. The `B::B(A)` constructor is called to create `bObject`, passing in the temporary `A` constructed in the last step.
4. Inside of the `B` constructor, the `B::object` object is default-constructed using `A::A()` because it was not in the constructor's initializer list.  *(The second "hello" is printed from here.)*
5. Finally, the body of the `B::B(A)` constructor is run, which assigns the value of the temporary `A` object (stored in `aObject`) to the `A` contained in `B::object`, which was constructed in the prior step. This assignment is accomplished by using the compiler-generated `A & A::operator=(A const &)` operator.

Comment: Why there is no "hello" printed when `object` is copied?

Comment: @wowofbob Because the complier-generated copy constructor does not call the default constructor. It's an entirely different constructor. It's equivalent in this case to `A(const A &) { }`.

Comment: @cdhowie Can you edit that comment into your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `B` constructor constructs all of the members of `B` before the body executes.  If you don't specify how to construct a member explicitly, the default constructor will be used.  To avoid calling the default constructor for `A`, you can specify the copy constructor:

```
B(A aObject) : object(aObject) {}
```

This will avoid calling the default constructor twice (once in `main()` and once in the `B()` constructor).

(There are also other ways to do this, such as using a move constructor.)

Comment: Assignment operator does not invoke constructor, but being a member does.

Comment: @Dialecticus: I understand what you are saying, but I don't know why you are telling me this.

Comment: Will this compile, with copy constructor undefined? Anyway, I think the point of this homework is to replace object with reference.

Comment: @Dialecticus A default copy-constructor is provided by the compiler if you do not delete it and if it would be well-formed.

Comment: @Dialecticus: To elaborate, the implicit copy constructor will be available unless a base class or non-static member does not have an accessible copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

String `A object;` is a place where you firstly create object of class A